# How to organize information in org mode such that it gives table as output?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm capturing results of my project in org-mode in this manner.

```
* Dataset

** Algorithm1
*** Metric1=value
*** Metric2=value

** Algorithm2
*** Metric1=value
.....
```

I would like to have this data in form of table where first row corresponds to metrics and first column corresponds to algorithms and other cells with values for metric. Can this be done in emacs/org-mode and how?

Comment: Well, org-mode can handle [tables](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tables.html), but the conversion is left for you to do with your favorite scripting language, as as is, it's not structured in a way org-mode understands.

Comment: Writing the first line by hand, `|metric1|metric2|metric3|`, and then running it through `sed s/^J*** Metric1=/|/g` for all metrics, then `sed s/**/|/g` should be a fair start.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you want, but you could use [properties and columns](http://orgmode.org/manual/Properties-and-Columns.html#Properties-and-Columns).

If you format you data like this,

```
#+COLUMNS: %25ITEM %7Metric1 %7Metric2

* Dataset

** Algorithm 1
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Metric1:  value 1
   :Metric2:  value 2
   :END:

** Algorithm 2
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Metric1:  value 1
   :Metric2:  value 2
   :END:
```

you can press <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> in the first line to refresh the columns settings, then <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> to display your data in column view (use <kbd>e</kbd> to edit a field and <kbd>q</kbd> to quit and return to the standard view):

```
ITEM           | Metric1 | Metric2 |
#+COLUMNS: %25ITEM %7Metric1 %7Metric2

* Dataset      |         |         | ...
** Algorithm 1 | value 1 | value 2 | ...
** Algorithm 2 | value 1 | value 2 | ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I am personally looking into this myself, and found this...

> Since column view is just an overlay over a buffer, it cannot be
>   exported or printed directly. If you want to capture a column view,
>   use a columnview dynamic block (see Dynamic blocks). http://orgmode.org/manual/Capturing-column-view.html